# Positioning text in a bar chart

Tags: plotting, labeling, text

I have several plots and for each one I need to insert a title. I'm using Epilog and the problem is that the final text position will change accordingly to the string size:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["Teste 1", Bold, 14], Scaled[{.1, .9}]]}]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["Another test", Bold, 14], Scaled[{.1, .9}]]}]
```

[image]

I believe that this happens because Epilog uses the center of string to position it. How can I make it use the position of the first letter?

Comment: Ok, thanks @Kuba

Answer (score 4):

I end up finding the answer. We just need to add the correct offset:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3},  
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["Teste 1", Bold, 14], Scaled[{.05, .9}], {-1, 0}]}]

BarChart[{1, 2, 3},  
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["Another test", Bold, 14], Scaled[{.05, .9}], {-1, 0}]}]
```